# Как код на jQuery переписать на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код jQuery. Как напиcать его на  JavaScript?

```js
$('body').on("click", "#rect", function() {
  var a = $(this).val();
  alert(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button type="button" class="rect" id="rect" value="316">5445</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так :

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.id == 'rect') console.log(e.target.value);
})
```

```html
<body>
  <button type="button" class="rect" id="rect" value="316">5445</button>
</body>
```

ПС: я клик прицепил на документ, вы же лучше прицепите его на элемент в котором будет появляться ваша кнопка

Вот пример с вашим кодом с комментария :

```js
var fox = document.querySelector("body");

setTimeout(function() {
  fox.innerHTML += '<button type="button" class="rect" id="rect" value="316">5445</button>';
}, 2000);


fox.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
  if (e.target.id == 'rect') alert(4);
});
```

```html
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: так ошибок нет но console.log не срабатывает

Comment: @Vadim видимо вы что-то не так сделали

Comment: var fox = document.querySelector("body");

fox.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.id == 'rect') 
    alert(4);
});

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (this.querySelector('#rect')) alert(this.querySelector('#rect').value);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var el = document.getElementById("rect");
el.addEventListener("click",function() {
  var a = this.value;
  alert(a);
})
```

```html
<body>
  <button type="button" class="rect" id="rect" value="316">5445</button>
</body>
```

Comment: этого элемента в самом начале в dom нет он появляется при определенном условии так вот если я в функцию вставлю то ок но за пределами не срабатывает

Comment: @Vadim тогда вам надо запустить этот код после того как добавляется этот элемент.

Comment: так jquery работает за пределами и все ок тут проблема

Comment: данный код работает только в функции

Comment: @Vadim вот вам там уже ответили.